# Firebase deploy failed

Tags: html, firebase, deployment

I wanted to deploy my one page project with firebase but I get this error. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFbii.png)

My init and deploy worked without an error and I selected to use my build folder.
I tried updating my dependencies but still same error.